# GO get K8S api server health status

Tags: go, kubernetes

I've a golang program which I need to add a new call to the `K8S API server` status (livez) api to get the health status.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/health-checks/

The program should run on **same cluster** of the api server and need to get the `/livez` status, I've tried to find this API in client-go lib but didn't find a way to achieve it...

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go

Is there a way to do it from Go program which is running on the same cluster that the API server run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update (final answer)

#### Appended

OP requested I modify my answer to show configs for "fine-tuned" or "specific" service accounts, without using cluster admin..

As far as I can tell, each pod has permissions to read from `/healthz` by default. For example, the following `CronJob` works just fine without using a `ServiceAccount` at all:

```yaml
# cronjob
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: is-healthz-ok-no-svc
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *" # at every fifth minute
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
######### serviceAccountName: health-reader-sa
          containers:
            - name: is-healthz-ok-no-svc
              image: oze4/is-healthz-ok:latest
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

[image]

#### Original

I went ahead and wrote a proof of concept for this. [You can find the full repo here](https://github.com/oze4/healthz), but the code is below.

#### main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
)

func main() {
    client, err := newInClusterClient()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    path := "/healthz"
    content, err := client.Discovery().RESTClient().Get().AbsPath(path).DoRaw()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ErrorBadRequst : %s\n", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    contentStr := string(content)
    if contentStr != "ok" {
        fmt.Printf("ErrorNotOk : response != 'ok' : %s\n", contentStr)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Success : ok!")
    os.Exit(0)
}

func newInClusterClient() (*kubernetes.Clientset, error) {
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        return &kubernetes.Clientset{}, errors.New("Failed loading client config")
    }
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        return &kubernetes.Clientset{}, errors.New("Failed getting clientset")
    }
    return clientset, nil
}
```

#### dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

#### deploy.yaml

(as CronJob)

```yaml
# cronjob
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: is-healthz-ok
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *" # at every fifth minute
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: is-healthz-ok
          containers:
            - name: is-healthz-ok
              image: oze4/is-healthz-ok:latest
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
---
# service account
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: is-healthz-ok
  namespace: default
---
# cluster role binding
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: is-healthz-ok
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: is-healthz-ok
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  ##########################################################################
  # Instead of assigning cluster-admin you can create your own ClusterRole #
  # I used cluster-admin because this is a homelab                         #
  ##########################################################################
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
```

#### Screenshot

of successful CronJob run

[image]

---

### Update 1

OP was asking how to deploy "in-cluster-client-config" so I am providing an example deployment (one that I am using)..

You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/oze4/service.remove-terminating-namespaces)

Example deployment (I am using a CronJob, but it could be anything):

#### cronjob.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: remove-terminating-namespaces-cronjob
spec:
  schedule: "0 */1 * * *" # at minute 0 of each hour aka once per hour
  #successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  #failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: svc-remove-terminating-namespaces
          containers:
          - name: remove-terminating-namespaces
            image: oze4/service.remove-terminating-namespaces:latest
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

#### rbac.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: svc-remove-terminating-namespaces
  namespace: default
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: crb-namespace-reader-writer
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: svc-remove-terminating-namespaces
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  ##########################################################################
  # Instead of assigning cluster-admin you can create your own ClusterRole #
  # I used cluster-admin because this is a homelab                         #
  ##########################################################################
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
```

---

### Original Answer

It sounds like what you are looking for is the "in-cluster-client-config" from client-go.

It is important to remember that when using an "in-cluster-client-config", the API calls within your Go code use the service account for "that" pod. Just wanted to make sure you were testing with an account that has permissions to read "/livez".

I tested the following code and I am able to get "livez" status..

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"

    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    "k8s.io/client-go/util/homedir"
)

func main() {
    // I find it easiest to use "out-of-cluster" for tetsing
    // client, err := newOutOfClusterClient()

    client, err := newInClusterClient()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    livez := "/livez"
    content, _ := client.Discovery().RESTClient().Get().AbsPath(livez).DoRaw()

    fmt.Println(string(content))
}

func newInClusterClient() (*kubernetes.Clientset, error) {
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        return &kubernetes.Clientset{}, errors.New("Failed loading client config")
    }
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        return &kubernetes.Clientset{}, errors.New("Failed getting clientset")
    }
    return clientset, nil
}

// I find it easiest to use "out-of-cluster" for tetsing
func newOutOfClusterClient() (*kubernetes.Clientset, error) {
    var kubeconfig *string
    if home := homedir.HomeDir(); home != "" {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    } else {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    }
    flag.Parse()

    // use the current context in kubeconfig
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // create the clientset
    client, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return client, nil
}
```

Comment: Hello! I want to test it but im getting two errors: 1. when running go mod init and vendor I got error "`go: finding module for package k8s.io/api/auditregistration/v1alpha1
apiserver imports
        k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes imports
        k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/auditregistration/v1alpha1 imports
        k8s.io/api/auditregistration/v1alpha1: module k8s.io/api@latest found (v0.19.2), but does not contain package k8s.io/api/auditregistration/v1alpha1` what I should do?

Comment: the second error is in this api `client.Discovery().RESTClient().Get().AbsPath(livez).DoRaw()`  error is: `Not enough arguments in call to 'client.Discovery().RESTClient().Get().AbsPath(livez).DoRaw'`

Comment: That is a problem with the SDK. That issue is specific to your machine, so you will need to troubleshoot it. Make sure your `go.mod` looks like this `require (
 k8s.io/api v0.17.0
 k8s.io/apimachinery v0.17.0
 k8s.io/client-go v0.17.0
)`

Comment: well, I was able to fix this, and when I run this using `outClusterConfig` im getting list of api ` fmt.Println(string(content))`  , but I want to `ping` to the api server `"/healthz",` endpoint and check if live, how we can achieve this ? this is the output `{
  "paths": [
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/etcd",
    "/healthz/log",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced", 
  ]
}
`

Comment: btw, if I change the value `livez := "/livez"` to `livez := "/foo"` I got the same results/list of api's

Comment: The list of apis means you are sending an incorrect url. The response contains a list of valid urls. When sending to am appropriate url the response should be "ok". Although, my guess is it has something to do with the pod not having permissions to read from livez. Do you get the same error when using out of cluster config?

Comment: Also to "ping" the endpoint you have to send a request to it. If the request responds with anything other than "ok' the endpoint should be considered dead and offline.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by incorrect url? I've tested the `outside the cluster option` and not inside yet and I've the full permission via the kubeconfig...do you konw what is the issue?

Comment: you also said the `Also to "ping" the endpoint you have to send a request to it.` , this is not the code that you posted? if not what else I should add ?

Comment: That is the code I posted. Sorry I misunderstood. When I run that code from out of cluster I get "ok". What happens if you run this command from the terminal? `kubectl get --raw='/readyz?verbose'`

Comment: when I run `kubectl get ns` I got the list of namespace and also i'm able to create  a pod CM etc, I dont have any problem as i have the full `kubeconfig` but when running `kubectl get --raw='/readyz?verbose'` I see `Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource` not sure way...

Comment: But when running ` kubectl get --raw='/healthz'` I got `ok%`

Comment: I changed the code to use `/healthz` (maybe its related to k8s version) and it works! from `outside the cluster`, now I want to test the `inside cluster`. Im creating a docker image but what about the service account, I'll appreciate  if you provide the steps in the answer how to do it as others can learn too and I close the question. thanks!

Comment: @bredstraruts I provided an example deployment that I am using in cluster. You should be able to mirror this. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @bredstraruts please see my final update. I went ahead and wrote a proof of concept for this that shows how to do exactly what you're wanting to do.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Great news! I want to test it now. in the `deploy` yaml I saw you provided some `crd` with `namesapce: defalut` , for which namespace you deployed the `application` and `all` the crd in the `deploy.yaml`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Is that a question?

Comment: yes, :)  for which namespace you deployed the application and all the crd in the deploy.yaml?

Comment: Yes, to the default. :)

Comment: I give you the full bounty :) thank you , could you please just add how can I use some restricted service account roles etc ?

Comment: Awesome! You bet. I'll update my answer when I have a couple minutes.

Comment: @bredstraruts please see my updated answer. Also, please make sure to mark this answer as accepted if it resolved your issue :)